# How to get Tweets of users who i am following using Account Activity API?

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to get tweets of users who i am following using [Account Activity API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/accounts-and-users/account-activity-api)?
Or there is any way to get tweets of specific users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! If your account is subscribed to the AA API then you should see Tweets mentioning you on the webhook. If you are interested in Tweets from specific users then use the timelines API.

Comment: Perfect! If their are no mentions on the Tweet, just a normal tweet from the following will i still get the tweet for that or i have to use Timeline API....

Comment: The timeline API is not a realtime notification; you will need to call it repeatedly to check to new information.

Comment: The AA API does not send Tweets for anyone you are following; it will only send events where your account is mentioned.

Comment: Finally i can get rid of my confusion, i thought it was possible from AA API. But in my opinion timeline data should be possible from AA API.

Comment: The title of the API explains that is is for *activities related to the account* - it is not a timeline API. Feel free to propose a use case and request changes via https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com if you would like an update to be considered.

Comment: Yes right! Tweets from following are related to timeline. If webhook showed tweets from following, that would be a good taste. bcz webhooks are great, don't have to call everytime. Streams are good too, but i will go with webhooks. Surely will propose a user case regarding this. Cheers!